# Connecting to Database contents to be used for a netbeans project

Tags: java, database, netbeans, database-connection, project

Im trying to gain access to my database using a project in order to input information like username and password so that if the input is correct, then i can access details about that certain account, but before all that, there's an error that says "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
and im not sure how to fix it, i checked other solutions saying to check my URL, which i have done and fixed but it still is an error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Connection con = null;        
Statement stmt = null;
try{
//REGISTER THE DRIVERS
Class.forName(JDBC_Driver1);
Class.forName(JDBC_Driver2);
//ESTABLISH CONNECTION TO DB
    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected Database....");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
    System.out.println("CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY");
}
catch (Exception e){
System.err.println(e);
```

Comment: You have two driver calls. I do not think this would work. It is likely getting confused.

Comment: How do i fix it then?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which IDE you are using. I will explain this in terms of the Netbeans IDE.

Firstly, you will need to make sure you have a Glassfish type server. They can be found in the "services" tab.

Secondly, you need to make sure your derby database is connected. In netbeans if it is not connected, it will have a broken looking icon next to it. If this is the case, right click and hit connect.

One of the benefits to a derby database is that it has a built in set of drivers, so it is unnecessary to provide a driver class.

If you are completely starting out fresh and have not changed your username or password, the following code has all of the default information to connect to the sample database that is created when you download glassfish server.

```
public class DataAccessDerby {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample";
    private static final String USER = "app";
    private static final String PASS = "app";
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;

    public void openConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataAccessDerby derby = new DataAccessDerby();
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected Database....");
            derby.openConnection();
            System.out.println("CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY");
            derby.closeConnection();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.